# Changes of percents in the result of a poll will be very small after one thousand of polls submitted?

Tags: statistics, applications

I saw an admin of an Instagram Channel created a poll with two option. and he said the following after a while:

> Statistics is interesting, َafter one thousands of people voted, the results in percent won't change more than about $1$ or $2$ percent, even after receiving one hundred thousand more votes!

I'm not an expert in statistics, but I want to know whether his claim is true or not? and why? ( I know theatrically if  thousands of people vote the same option it changes the result significantly but I want to know about it in practice not only theory).

Comment: The essential assumption is that the first thousand votes are a random sample of all the votes.  This is not true in many real world situations, where the first votes cast or counted can come from a distinct population.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a very simple model. There are $1000$ i.i.d voters $I_i$, $i=1,..,1000$ for some binary option (pro something, that is coded $1$, or against something, that is coded $0$). Hence, the estimated proportion $\hat{p}$ of the pro voters is
$$
\hat{p} = \frac{1}{1000}\sum_{i=1}^{1000}I_i.
$$
Now, assume that the estimated $p$ is $0.5$, i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^{100} I_i = 500 $. Consider that another $100$ voters voted $1$, hence for $n=1100$ the estimated proportion is about $0.545$, that is a change of $\approx 9\%$. However,  the unconditional probability for such a change is
$
p^{100}
$. That is, very very unlikely for every reasonable $p$.
Since the sample size is large enough ($1000$), you can approximate its sample distribution using the central limit theorem, i.e.,
$$
\hat{p} \sim^{approx} N\left(p, \frac{p(1-p)}{1000}\right).
$$
Thus the estimated standard error is $\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})/1000}$.  Hence, for $\hat{p} = 0.5$, which is the most unstable result since $p(1-p)$ is maximized at $p=0.5$,  is $0.016$. Taking $\pm$ two times this standard error, you get the approximated $95\%$ CI, which is $[0.468, 5.32]$. Intuitively, it captures the uncertainty of the estimator under the aforementioned assumptions, hence it is unlikely (less than $0.05$) that the true $p$ lies  outside this interval. For checking the validity of the specific statement you need to provide the sample proportion and the underlying assumptions of the voters distribution.

Comment: I'll add that with continued sampling, you'd expect somewhat less variability than what the CI suggests. The CI represents where the true value of *p* is likely to fall, and indicates the likely outcome of another *independent sampling* of the population. But here, we already have 1000 survey responses as an "anchor", so it's not an independent sampling and there will be less variability in the result. If you only add 1 more response, for example, the estimate of *p* cannot change by more than 1/1000. If we have enough new responses, though, it is effectively an independent sample.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I haven't mention convergence, which is the really what the question is about (i.e., assessing precision \ stability of the results, by increasing the sample size). To make this discussion more concrete, the OP needs to assume that the sample is indeed random and the voters are i.i.d, which is highly unlikely in Instagram poll for a certain group of voters).